# My Mic is disabled while playing overwatch. Why?

Tags: overwatch

I have no idea why. Sometimes plugging in and plugging out works. It no longer does.

Here is the screen shot

[image]

See left upper corner. Disabled mic. No reason why.

Comment: Is it muted in the audio options menu?

Comment: don't play aroun in menu. think I have open mic.

Comment: That symbol is there when you have an open mic but have yourself muted. Try to press "m", the standard mute/unmute button.

Comment: @Nutty You should probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This symbol is there, if you have an open mic and are muted.

To mute/unmute yourself you can try pressing the standard button <kbd>M</kbd>, or you can look it up in your settings, should you have rebound the key.

Note: the font is either blue, green or orange, depending on if you are in the team, group or match voice chat, respectively.